# Why is $\det(e^X)=e^{\operatorname{tr}(X)}$?

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

I've seen on Wikipedia that for a complex matrix $X$, $\det(e^X)=e^{\operatorname{tr}(X)}$.

It is clearly true for a diagonal matrix. What about other matrices ?

The series-based definition of exp is useless here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A alternative to doing this by normal forms which perhaps assumes more but is much more natural to me is (as suggested in the comment on [$\det(\exp X)=e^{\mathrm{Tr}\, X}$ for 2 dimensional matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299528/det-exp-x-e-mathrmtr-x-for-2-dimensional-matrices?rq=1)) to note that it clearly holds for diagonalizable matrices (see the duplicate [How to prove $\det(e^A) = e^{\operatorname{tr}(A)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322640/how-to-prove-detea-e-operatornametra) ...), and by

1. the continuity of $\det, \mathrm{tr}$ and $\exp$
2. the density of diagonalizable matrices in the space of all complex matrices ([Diagonalizable matrices with complex values are dense in set of $n\times n$ complex matrices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/diagonalizable-matrices-with-complex-values-are-dense-in-set-of-n-times-n-comp))

we have the result more generally for *all* matrices.

Comment: I've thought of this proof too. Are you sure it is valid ? You're dealing with diagonalizable matrices, not diagonal ones.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's enough for $X$ to be diagonalisable for the argument to work (because the trace and determinant are the same for similar matrices). So, equality holds on a dense set of matrices. Everything in the equality is continuous, so we can pass from a dense set to the full space.

Comment: OK. @Sharkos: you should add that the trace and determinant invariance in your answer to make it perfect.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is upper triangular, then this is clear.

If the claim holds for a matrix $Y$, then it holds for any $X$ similar to $Y$.

By Jordan decomposition, each $X$ is similar to an upper triangular matrix $Y$ (of a special form, but never mind).

Thus, the claim holds for all $X$.

Comment: Well the Jordan decomposition is not a cakewalk to prove, is it ? Anyway, I'm glad it does the trick.

Comment: @GabrielR. Noone is saying it is. But once you have it, why not use it? The argument only uses that a matrix can be brought into an upper triangular form - this may be more elementary.

Comment: It definitely is more elementary. You need the existence of an eigenvector, choose a complementary subspace, do induction and you are done.