# For a non-diagonalizable $n \times n$ matrix, how to prove that $\exists (A_m)$ is diagonalizable matrix such that $A_m$ converges to $A$.

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

For a non-diagonalizable $n \times n$ matrix, how to prove that $\exists (A_m)$ is diagonalizable matrix such that $A_m$ converges to $A$. Here we define norm on $M(n, \Bbb C)$ s.t $||X||=(\sum _{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_{ij}|^2)^{1/2}$ and $A_m$ converges to $A$ iff $||A_m - A|| \to 0$ as $m\to \infty$

I was thinking to use Jordon Canonical form but can't get it as the calculation are getting twisted. If someone has some detailed proof please help.

Comment: see answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/diagonalizable-matrices-with-complex-values-are-dense-in-set-of-n-times-n-comp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of all diagonalizable matrices is dense in the space of all $n\times n$ matrices; you'll find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/diagonalizable-matrices-with-complex-values-are-dense-in-set-of-n-times-n-comp). This is enough to prove what you want.

Comment: This is the *exact claim* the OP wants to prove, so certainly enough.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff No. It is equivalent, but it is not the same statement. However, if the OP states that, for him or her, the statements are trivially equivalent, then I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you remark it boils down to Jordan normal normal form, from which we see it suffices to handle the nilpotent case.
For which we have for example

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon&1&0\\
0&\eta&1\\
0&0&\nu
\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $\epsilon, \eta, \nu$ limit to zero in such a way that they are distinct, and so the matrix is diagonalizable, its minimal polynomial being the product of distinct factors.