# trace, determinant and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do i show that the trace and determinants are equal the sum and product of eigenvalues of a square matrix? I just need some hints or references here. It is not a homework problem.

Comment: For me the easiest way would be to note that it holds for diagonalizable matrices and then use that these are dense.

Comment: thanks @TobiasKildetoft. What do you mean by dense?

Comment: Do You know the Jordan normal form of a matrix?

Comment: The question about the determinant has been asked here before, please look there first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

$$M=T\Lambda T^{-1}$$ you draw $$|M|=|T||\Lambda||T^{-1}|=|T|\prod\lambda_k\frac1{|T|}.$$

---

More generally,

$$|M-\lambda I|=|T||\Lambda-\lambda I||T^{-1}|=|T|\prod(\lambda_k-\lambda)\frac1{|T|}$$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$, and all coefficients in the developments will match. In particular, the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ is the sum of the Eigenvalues by Vieta, and is also the trace of $M$ (it is the sum of the products of all $\lambda$'s in $n-1$ diagonal elements and the constant coefficient in the remaining diagonal element).

By this reasoning, you will find $n-2$ other invariants (of which the trivial leading coefficient $1$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You can prove, by induction, that in the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$:
$$
\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots + a_1\lambda+a_0
$$
we have: 
$$a_{n-1}=-tr(A) \qquad a_0=(-1)^n det(A)$$

Then use [Viète's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on @TobiasKildetoft's comment.

The result is trivial for diagonal matrices, and applies also to diagonalizable ones because any invertible $S$ satisfies$$\operatorname{tr}SAS^{-1}=\operatorname{tr}AS^{-1}S=\operatorname{tr}A$$and$$\det SAS^{-1}=\det S\det A\det(S^{-1})=\det S\det A(\det S)^{-1}=\det A.$$For $n\times n$ matrices, the difference between $\operatorname{tr}A$ and the sum of $A$'s eigenvalues is a polynomial function of its entries. (This relies on the diagonalizable matrices being "dense", and this property is defined and proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/diagonalizable-matrices-with-complex-values-are-dense-in-set-of-n-times-n-comp).) And the only way for this polynomial to vanish on all diagonalizable $A$ is for it to vanish in general. The same argument applies to determinants.

Comment: +1 Don't You mean $\operatorname{tr}(SAS^{-1})=\operatorname{tr}(ASS^{-1})=...$?

Comment: @PeterMelech No, because $\operatorname{tr}UVW$ is equal to $\operatorname{tr}VWU$ but not necessarily $\operatorname{tr}VUW$. Of course, your comment was pointing out I'd accidentally left out the $W$, so thanks! Fixed.

Comment: Yes, I made a typo in my comment, anyway that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Every matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is similar to its [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) J, i.e. there exists a matrix $T\in \operatorname{Gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ so that
$$A=T^{-1}JT$$
which implies:
$$\det(A)=\det(T)^{-1}\det(J)\det(T)=\det(J)$$
and
$$\operatorname{tr}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(T^{-1}JT)=\operatorname{tr}(TT^{-1}J)=\operatorname{tr}(J)$$
where we used that $\det:\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a monoid-homomorphism and that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ for all $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.
For the Jordan matrix $J$ the claim is obvious.