# Group of matrices form a manifold or euclidean space

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, euclidean-geometry, linear-groups

There is a very interesting question [How can a group of matrices form a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420265/how-can-a-group-of-matrices-form-a-manifold).  From the answers it looks more like group of matrices form euclidean space than a general manifold. I understand that euclidean space is a manifold, but manifold is very general and has curvature.  My question is what exactly makes a group of matrices a manifold but not simply a euclidean space.

- I am not a mathematician so please correct me if there is anything wrong with the question or the way I posed it.

Comment: Under addition, they *can* be Euclidean.  However, all the interesting math happens multiplicatively, where they usually aren't flat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$, for instance. This is the group of the $2\times2$ orthogonal matrices whose determinant is $1$. But then$$SO(2,\mathbb{R})=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,\theta\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$This can be seen as a *circle* in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore, it is naturally a manifold, but in no way an Euclidean space.

Comment: circle is a 1-dimensional manifold, right ?.  A $n\times n$ matrix group should form an $n$ dimensional manifold right ?.

Comment: Wrong, as my example shows.

Comment: which part is wrong ?.  $n \times n$ matrix group forms $$ dimensional manifold part ?. Is there any relationship between matrix dimension and manifold dimension ?

Comment: If a group of $n\times n$ matrices forms a manifold, then the dimension of that manifold can take **any** value from the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n^2\}$. The example that I gave is a case in which $n=2$ and the dimension is $1$.

Comment: great. Thank you.  If you got some time, can you please check my other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994146/group-of-rectangular-matrices

Answer (score 3):

In the question to which you refer the group of matrices is given a manifold structure by virtue of its embedding in a Euclidean space. So for example you can think of a torus as a two dimensional manifold (with interesting curvature) by using the differentiable structure it gets from the usual embedding as a curved surface in $3$-space. That doesn't make the torus a Euclidean space.