# Rectangular matrices

Tags: matrices, manifolds, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix factorized into $A = UV'$ where $U$ is $m \times k$ and $V$ is $n \times k$.
I define the group of matrices $(UR,VR^{-1})$ where $R \in O(k)$ i.e. orthogonal group of $k \times k$.
Since for any value of $R$, the factorization holds true, can we say that this group forms a manifold ?.  If so, what will be dimension of this manifold ?

Comment: Yes. you are correct. I missed that point.  btw, what will be the dimension of this manifold. I read it i $k^2$ dimensional.  How it will be $k^2$ ?

Comment: Which manifold? What is $V'$?

Comment: it is transpose of $V$. manifold corresponding to the rank $k$ rectangular matrix  defined by $URR^{-1}V'$

Comment: But since $URR^{-1}V'=UV'=A$, the dimension is $mn$?

Comment: In a paper it reads 'The decomposition is not unique. For any invertible $k \times k$ matrix $R$, (UR, VR^{-1}) provides a factorization equivalent to (U,V), resulting in a $k^2$ dimensional manifold of equivalent solutions'.  The manifold part about equivalent solution is not well understood by me. Can you tell what exactly the author meant ?