# When are powers of square matrices linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have an $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$, is $1, A, A^2,...,A^{n^2}$ always linearly independent?

Comment: No. For instance, you can have $A=0$ (the zero matrix), or $A=I$ (the identity). I guess you can ask when they are linearly independent, but I'm not sure if this is known

Comment: Cayley-Hamilton says $A$ satisfies a polynomial of degree...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, never, because the space of $n\times n$ matrices has dimension $n^2$ and you have $n^2+1$ matrices there.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry. That was dumb. Would the first 1, A, ..., A^{n^2-1} matrices be linearly independent?

Comment: No, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/36662/589.