# If $A \in K^{n\times n}$ is $\{I_n , A, A^{2}, A^{3}, \dots, A^{n^{2}-1} \}$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Decide whether the following set is linearly independent on $K$:
>   $\{I_n , A, A^{2}, A^{3}, \dots, A^{n^{2}-1}\}$, with $A \in K^{n\times n}$, $n\geq 2$, $K$ a field.

I know I have to put conditions on $A$ and depends on $K$. Some hints to work this out in easy way.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/36662/589.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** To determine whether $\{I_n, A, \dots, A^{n^2 - 1}\}$ is linearly dependent or not, we have to see whether we can find scalars $c_0, c_1, \dots, c_{n^2-1} \in K$, not all zero, such that $$c_0I + c_1A + \dots c_{n^2 - 1}A^{n^2-1} = 0.$$ We can reformulate the left hand side by considering the polynomial, of degree at most $n^2-1$, $p(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \dots + c_{n^2-1}x^{n^2-1}$; if not all of the scalars are non-zero, then $p$ is not the zero polynomial. The above equation now becomes $p(A) = 0$. Do you know of any results about a matrix satisfying a polynomial equation?

Comment: no. but I can read about it (tell the name of the result). Hamilton-Caley maybe?

Comment: @Elll That, and also the relation between the minimal and characteristic polynomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Ok. I'm reading about it . If I can't solve it (with the new info), I'm gonna ask again. thanks

Comment: @Ell: Cayley-Hamilton will work. Can you see why?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, the answer (to the question) is no (not independent). am i right?

Comment: @NikosM. You are correct.

Comment: yes. the answer is no. cause every matrix have a minimal polynomials ($\not= 0$) / $P(A)=0$. then there's $(c_{0} , ...., c_{n^2 - 1})$ $\not= 0$. then the set is l.d.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese   Very nicely put. Without giving everything on the platter, enough hints to make someone learn. Definitely +1